# Building WebRTC Audio Processing code ONLY for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, build, webrtc

The goal is to integrate just the WebRTC audio processing module code into iOS to use in my App. I'm running into a whole bunch of issues like

1. The ASM code files need to be removed and not compiled.
2. Objective-C++ does not deal well with the virtual AudioProcessing class (So I'm having an issue even trying to test it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33150058/using-webrtc-c-classes-in-objective-c-gives-exc-bad-access)
3. There seem to be several references thread functionality which make me nervous that my application will crash if I try to use them.

I already have a slight amount of experience in getting it to work on C++ for x86_64 processors. What are the steps in getting this module to work properly for iOS devices and compiling in Xcode?

Comment: WebRTC for iOS is a bag of hurt. I managed to compile it (all) some time ago using the instructions from [WebRTC website](http://www.webrtc.org/native-code/ios)

Comment: [Compiling WebRTC for iOS is made pretty easy by these awesome people](http://tech.pristine.io/automated-webrtc-building/)

Comment: Were you able to extract the audio proccessing module and use it in your app?

Comment: @narduk Yes, I was. I think I just ended up deleting the x86, mips, and neon ASM files. They seem like they were meant to be specialized versions of the generic classes.So I removed the references to them in the files and just used the generic classes. The other errors I listed were actually just my fault. In the end I got it working just fine. If I had to do it again from scratch, I'd actually just take a look at the pjsip code and how they do it (or borrow it verbatim if possible). They integrate webrtc audio processing in the same way that I want to. Also, they have iOS support.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to compile the WebRTC API for iOS. By far the easiest way is to install [cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/) and use:

```
pod "libjingle_peerconnection"
```

Another way is to do it yourself, using the [provided guidelines](http://www.webrtc.org/native-code/ios). This can be a bit tricky to manage, but it has the advantage of being able to patch the code to suit your needs before compiling. Seeing as you ultimately only want the audio processing module, I'd say this is the way to go for you.

A third option is to use one of the various available SDKs that implement the underlying WebRTC code for you. Their disadvantage is usually that they aren't free.

Comment: Will compiling the WebRTC API code in the first option you provide using the pod also provide access and header files for the audio processing module?

Comment: @mikealeonetti I am not sure, I have the need to edit the source files every now and then. I think you only get the headers+lib though, the sources are pretty big...

Comment: indeed. For the second option, I could modify the code in its entirety, you're saying if necessary. I only need to have access to the audio processing API as is. So perhaps the first option may be best if I have the function access I need. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @mikealeonetti I'm not so sure you can access the lower levels of the WebRTC API through the lib. You want to use the audio processing module for something, right? I don't think you can just use it by including the WebRTC lib, even when you know how to navigate through it's namespaces. I really think your best bet is to download the sources and search for the files manually. Then isolate them and their dependencies and include them in your project.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably compile the libs from WebRTC-ios source using the build script under directory src/webrtc/build/ios/build_ios_libs.sh. Set up the build environment following the official guide and run the build script. Then you could find all the libs using by webrtc-ios under directory src/out_ios_libs where you should find the audio processing libs you need.
Find the specific headers and *.a you'll need to link with your App.

Here is the WebRTC site:https://webrtc.org/